# Recovering lost multiprocessing.Queue items when a worker Process dies

Tags: python, algorithm, queue, multiprocessing

My scenario is this:

- I've got worker which enqueues tasks into a multiprocessing.Queue() if said is empty. This is to ensure execution of tasks follow a certain priority and multiprocessing.Queue() doesn't do priorities.
- There are a number of workers which pop from the mp.Queue and do some stuff. Sometimes (<0.1%) these fail and die without having the possibility to re-enqueue the task.
- My tasks are locked via a central database and may only run once (hard requirement). For this they have certain states which they can transition from/to.

My current solution: Let all workers answer via another queue which tasks have been completed and introduce a deadline by which a task has to be done. Reset the task and re-enqueue it if a deadline has been reached. This has the problem that the solution is "soft", i.e. the deadline is arbitrary.

I am searching for the simplest possible solution. Is there a simpler or a more stringent solution to this?

Comment: Can you change the worker so that when a task fails, the worker itself re-enqueues the task?

Comment: What happens when a task fails? A Python exception you could catch?

Comment: @unutbu This is already the case, if they fail they re-enqueue. They can however fail for other reasons without the worker having control over them (segfault, etc).

Comment: @JanneKarila Nope. Think about it as kill -9

Comment: Note this warning from [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues): If a process is killed using Process.terminate() or os.kill() while it is trying to use a Queue, then the data in the queue is likely to become corrupted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution uses three queues to keep track of the work (simulated as `WORK_ID`):

- `todo_q`: Any work to be done (including that to be redone if the process died in-flight)
- `start_q`: Any work that has been started by a process
- `finish_q`: Any work that has been completed

Using this method you should not need a timer.  As long as you assign a process identifier and keep track of assignments, check to see whether `Process.is_alive()`.  If the process died, then add that work back to the todo queue.

In the code below, I simulate a worker process dying 25% of the time...

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from Queue import Empty
from random import choice as rndchoice
import time

def worker(id, todo_q, start_q, finish_q):
    """multiprocessing worker"""
    msg = None
    while (msg!='DONE'):
        try:
            msg = todo_q.get_nowait()    # Poll non-blocking on todo_q
            if (msg!='DONE'):
                start_q.put((id, msg))   # Let the controller know work started
                time.sleep(0.05)
                if (rndchoice(range(3))==1):
                    # Die a fraction of the time before finishing
                    print "DEATH to worker %s who had task=%s" % (id, msg)
                    break
                finish_q.put((id, msg))  # Acknowledge work finished
        except Empty:
            pass
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    NUM_WORKERS = 5
    WORK_ID = set(['A','B','C','D','E']) # Work to be done, you will need to
                                    #    name work items so they are unique
    WORK_DONE = set([])             # Work that has been done
    ASSIGNMENTS = dict()            # Who was assigned a task
    workers = dict()
    todo_q = Queue()
    start_q = Queue()
    finish_q = Queue()

    print "Starting %s tasks" % len(WORK_ID)
    # Add work
    for work in WORK_ID:
        todo_q.put(work)

    # spawn workers
    for ii in xrange(NUM_WORKERS):
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(ii, todo_q, start_q, finish_q))
        workers[ii] = p
        p.start()

    finished = False
    while True:
        try:
            start_ack = start_q.get_nowait()  # Poll for work started
            ## Check for race condition between start_ack and finished_ack
            if not ASSIGNMENTS.get(start_ack[0], False):
                ASSIGNMENTS[start_ack[0]] = start_ack   # Track the assignment
                print "ASSIGNED worker=%s task=%s" % (start_ack[0], 
                    start_ack[1])
                WORK_ID.remove(start_ack[1])      # Account for started tasks
            else:
                # Race condition. Never overwrite existing assignments
                # Wait until the ASSIGNMENT is cleared
                start_q.put(start_ack)
        except Empty:
            pass

        try:
            finished_ack = finish_q.get_nowait()  # Poll for work finished
            # Check for race condition between start_ack and finished_ack
            if (ASSIGNMENTS[finished_ack[0]][1]==finished_ack[1]):
                # Clean up after the finished task
                print "REMOVED worker=%s task=%s" % (finished_ack[0], 
                    finished_ack[1])
                del ASSIGNMENTS[finished_ack[0]]
                WORK_DONE.add(finished_ack[1])
            else:
                # Race condition. Never overwrite existing assignments
                # It was received out of order... wait for the 'start_ack'
                finish_q.put(finished_ack)
            finished_ack = None
        except Empty:
            pass

        # Look for any dead workers, and put their work back on the todo_q
        if not finished:
            for id, p in workers.items():
                status = p.is_alive()
                if not status:
                    print "    WORKER %s FAILED!" % id
                    # Add to the work again...
                    todo_q.put(ASSIGNMENTS[id][1])
                    WORK_ID.add(ASSIGNMENTS[id][1])
                    del ASSIGNMENTS[id]      # Worker is dead now
                    del workers[id]
                    ii += 1
                    print "Spawning worker number", ii
                    # Respawn a worker to replace the one that died
                    p = Process(target=worker, args=(ii, todo_q, start_q, 
                        finish_q))
                    workers[ii] = p
                    p.start()
        else:
            for id, p in workers.items():
                p.join()
                del workers[id]
            break

        if (WORK_ID==set([])) and (ASSIGNMENTS.keys()==list()):
            finished = True
            [todo_q.put('DONE') for x in xrange(NUM_WORKERS)]
        else:
            pass
    print "We finished %s tasks" % len(WORK_DONE)
```

Running this on my laptop...

```
mpenning@mpenning-T61:~$ python queueack.py
Starting 5 tasks
ASSIGNED worker=2 task=C
ASSIGNED worker=0 task=A
ASSIGNED worker=4 task=B
ASSIGNED worker=3 task=E
ASSIGNED worker=1 task=D
DEATH to worker 4 who had task=B
DEATH to worker 3 who had task=E
    WORKER 3 FAILED!
Spawning worker number 5
    WORKER 4 FAILED!
Spawning worker number 6
REMOVED worker=2 task=C
REMOVED worker=0 task=A
REMOVED worker=1 task=D
ASSIGNED worker=0 task=B
ASSIGNED worker=2 task=E
REMOVED worker=2 task=E
DEATH to worker 0 who had task=B
    WORKER 0 FAILED!
Spawning worker number 7
ASSIGNED worker=5 task=B
REMOVED worker=5 task=B
We finished 5 tasks
mpenning@mpenning-T61:~$
```

I tested this with over 10000 work items at a 25% mortality rate.

Comment: This sounds promising. I'm going to try that.

Comment: I rewrote it a bit. I now use only 2 queues, one in each direction. On the result side I added a small protocol (I return a 3-tuple) that signals what happened. That way I stay extensible and it only added about 20 lines of code in total. Anyway: The first real-world test is complete and it worked great.